# Updating existing index in pymongo

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

I'm using pymongo and want to update an index from being unique to being unique and sparse.  Both `ensure_index` and `create_index` don't seem to want to update the index that already exists.  I'm running mongo 2.2.0

```
In [1]: coll.index_information()
Out[1]:
{u'_id_': {u'key': [(u'_id', 1)], u'v': 1},
 u'foo_1': {u'key': [(u'foo', 1)], u'unique': True, u'v': 1}}

In [2]: coll.ensure_index([('foo', 1)], unique=True, sparse=True)

In [3]: coll.index_information()
Out[3]:
{u'_id_': {u'key': [(u'_id', 1)], u'v': 1},
 u'foo_1': {u'key': [(u'foo', 1)], u'unique': True, u'v': 1}}

In [4]: coll.drop_index('foo_1')

In [5]: coll.ensure_index([('foo', 1)], unique=True, sparse=True)
Out[5]: u'foo_1'

In [6]: coll.index_information()
Out[6]:
{u'_id_': {u'key': [(u'_id', 1)], u'v': 1},
 u'foo_1': {u'key': [(u'foo', 1)], u'sparse': True, u'unique': True, u'v': 1}}
```

Any ideas? I can't exactly do what I did here on a production database and just drop the index and re-create it.

Comment: If there are no alternatives, and you are running replica or shard in production, then you can consider building using : http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/build-indexes-on-replica-sets/#procedure
So, you can drop the index on secondary and build the same with sparse true. This should work fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MongoDB does not support updating indexes once created. I can't find that documented anywhere but none of the drivers have the ability to mutate an existing index.

If the issue on production with the drop/create is having a period of time without the index in place then, you can create the new index with a non-default name and once it is finished being created drop the default named version.

If the issue is the load on the servers while creating the index there is a strategy to create the index using secondaries:

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/build-indexes-on-replica-sets/#procedure

Basically you pull a member out of the replica set (no --replSet option, different port) , build the index locally, bring it back. Pull the next member out, build the index locally, add it back, rinse, repeat.

Comment: Good idea. From experimenting it looks like mongo also doesn't care if there's a different name. But it does work if I create the original index only descending, then drop the original index and re-create it with sparse=true, then drop the temporary index.